# Call overridden method from base class

Tags: c++

How to call overridden `bar` method from base class in the following scenario?

There is requirement that callback should always call method `foo` which should call `bar` which is overridden by latest derived class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

std::function<void(void)> callback = nullptr;

class Base {
 public:
  Base(Base* ptr) { callback = std::bind(&Base::foo, *ptr); }

  virtual ~Base() {}

  virtual void foo() {
    bar();  // How call foo() from Derived instead of Base?
  }
  virtual void bar() { cout << "Base::bar" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived() : Base(this) {}

  virtual void bar() override { cout << "Derived::bar" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  Base* b = new Derived();

  cout << "**callback**" << endl;
  callback();  // output should be 'Derived::bar'

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding the virtual method with the derived object improperly, slicing the derived object. Try this (* is removed)

```
Base(Base *ptr){
    callback = std::bind(&Base::foo, ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method that avoids `std::bind()` altogether:

```cpp
Base(Base *ptr){
        callback = [this]() { foo(); };
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/pEs9ta

Note that this requires at least C++11.